# Broadcast message to all EC2 instances in a auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Is there a correct way of routing a request to ALL instances in an autoscaling group instead of just to one? I suppose I could simply iterate through the addresses of the autoscaling group and send each request individually but I'm wondering whether there is a better way.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @shoopdelang: found an answer?I'm having the same problem